# App.config and web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, app-config

> How do i read from app.config and web.config.

app.config  reading is as follows .how do i read from web.config

```
 using System.Configuration;

 string configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["countoffiles"];
 string configvalue2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logfilelocation"];
```

> also why do we store in these config files?
>
> And How do i read from a user defined tag `<display>` in app.config below ??

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <configuration>
       <display>
         <add key="countoffiles" value="7" />
         <add key="logfilelocation" value="abc.txt" />
      </display>
    </configuration>
```

> what is the difference between values stored in app.config and web.config?
>     How do i decide where to keep certain data?

[image]

> i got this error when i added  `<display>` tag to the web.config in MVC application.Any clues on why??

Answer (score 3):

`Web.Config` is used for applications hosted at IIS (Websites, Webservices)

`App.Config` is used for any other .NET applications like (WinForms, WPF, Windows Services)

---

To read from custom section I would go that way:

```
NameValueCollection displaySection = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("display");
string countoffiles = displaySection ["countoffiles"];
string logfilelocation = displaySection ["logfilelocation"];
```

---

In regards to configuring custom sections, please check that article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

---

Comment: i have seen app.config in web applications as well.why we use that.can we  add app.config in web applications aas well

Comment: what is the difference in reading from web.config and app.config?code wise

Comment: I don't think there is any difference. The just have different purposes.

Comment: Another doubt, Can i add a user defined tag`<display>` anywhere in web.config and read its values